# Running two for loops through the same array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop, clone

I'm trying to run two for loops through the same array to clone a bunch of items, one going forwards the other going backwards, but it seems to only output the second array. Is there an issue trying to do this? This is my set up:

I first push the elements I want into the array.

```
var cloneArr = new Array();
$('.element').each(function(){
  var clone = $(this).clone();
  cloneArr.push(clone);
});
```

I then run two for loops to append and prepend each item around the original items.

```
for (i = 0; i < elementLength; i++) {
   $('.element-parent').append(cloneArr[i]);
}
for (i = elementLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   $('.element-parent').prepend(cloneArr[i]);
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that they each work by themself but wont work together. It will only add whichever loop is placed second. I've tried creating two different arrays and calling the second array when the first is finished, but get the same results.

Does anyone know how I could achieve this or what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you are appending and prepending the very same element. you should clone it twice.

Comment: As I said, I've tried running two different arrays of clones and get the same result.

Comment: @user2339729, you made two different arrays, but did you put the same variable into both? You need to run `$(this).clone();` twice to create two different clones.

Answer (score 2):

you are appending and prepending the very same element. you should clone it twice.

```
for (i = 0; i < elementLength; i++) {
  $('.element-parent').append(cloneArr[i]);
}
for (i = elementLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  $('.element-parent').prepend(cloneArr[i].clone()); //<-- here you are!!
}
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for. I figured it would be something simple that I overlooked. Works perfectly, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to place the same element into a node twice (`cloneArr[i]` is a reference to a node). Since the node already exists in the parent node, it effectively moves where the node resides under the parent. It doesn't matter that you ran it through two different loops, you're still referencing the same node.

```js
var $clone = $('p').clone();
$clone.text('Clone');
$('div').append($clone);
$('div').prepend($clone);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<p>Original</p>
```

Comment: You say what's going wrong, but you aren't providing an answer, you just provided another example what doesn't work.

Comment: I explained why it isn't producing the desired result. It only takes one extra thought to figure out that you need to clone the node for every time you want to insert it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var appendArr = new Array();
var prependArr = new Array();
$('.element').each(function(){
  appendArr.push($(this).clone());
  prependArr.push($(this).clone());
});

var elementLength = appendArr.length;
for (i = 0; i < elementLength; i++) {
   $('.element-parent').append(appendArr[i]);
}
for (i = elementLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   $('.element-parent').prepend(prependArr[i]);
}
```

You need to clone the element twice. You're currently creating a single clone, then appending it, then moving it afterwards by prepending. Here's some code that's similar in form to yours, and [here's a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4afv9jd5/) to see it in action.